# Cannot see why convergence to zero follows from two hypothesis

Tags: calculus

I read a proof which at some point reaches a sequence of this kind:

$b_m \leq m^{-1+1/p} g(m) /p$, where $p \in (1,2)$ and $0 < g(m) \rightarrow 0$

Now it is interested in showing that $\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\sum_{m=1}^n b_m \rightarrow 0$.

It claims that it follows from the fact that $\sum_{m=1}^n m^{-1+1/p} \leq K n^{1/p}$ and that $g$ goes to zero. But from those two facts I can only see that the desired limit is finite, not necessarily zero.

If someone could point me to a convergence criterion that can be used to prove that the limit is zero I would be thankful.

Comment: Presumably we also have $0\leq b_m$?

Comment: Yes!, actually $b_m = |c_m|$ and the original problem is proving that $c_m$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe that $$\frac{1}{n^c}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\sim\frac{1}{n^c}\sum_{j=N}^n a_j$$ for any $c>0$ and $N\in\mathbb N$ fixed.

To the original question, note that the constant $p$ in the expression of $b_m$ doesn't affect the convergence, so let $\varepsilon>0$. Then using the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^n j^{-1+1/p}\leq K\cdot n^{1/p}$, take $N$ large enough so that $g(n)<\varepsilon/K$ for all $n\geq N$. Now $$\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\sim\frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\sum_{j=N}^n b_j< \frac{\varepsilon}{K}\cdot K=\varepsilon.$$ Note that this approach only requires $p>0$, so it is slightly more general than the original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $N$ such that $g(m) <\epsilon$ for $m \geq N$. For $n >N$ we have $n^{-1/p} \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}b_m=n^{-1/p} \sum\limits_{m=1}^{N}b_m+n^{-1/p} \sum\limits_{m=N+1}^{n}b_m$. The second term is less than $\epsilon K/p$. The first term tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I upvoted the answer but accepted the other because it arrived first.